# SQL date with fixed day and month but relative year

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, business-objects, date-arithmetic

I've created a report in BusinessObjects WEBI but I would like to customize the underlying SQL so that the **year** in the date range changes based on when the query is run, leaving the day and month unchanged

This example ...

```
WHERE
ACT_ENDDT  BETWEEN  '01-10-2019 00:00:00'  AND  '30-09-2020 00:00:00'
```

... is desirable if I ran the query now (current year -1 AND current year, respectively) but if I were to run this query in 2021 I want those years to change to 2020 and 2021, respectively, keeping the day and months the same (10/1 and 9/30).

I searched through a few resources like sqltutorial and w3schools but I'm barely a novice at this and can't wrap my head around how to make it work. I also tried the solution provided here in thread 28707795 as such:

```
ACT_ENDDT  BETWEEN  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate())-1,10,1) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()),9,30)
```

... but end up with a message that DATEFROMPARTS is an invalid identifier.

Is there a way to hard code part of the date and have a modifier attached to it for just the year, e.g. `... BETWEEN  '01-10-'&[*currentyear* - 1] ...`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Side note: `ACT_ENDDT BETWEEN  '01-10-2019 00:00:00'  AND  '30-09-2020 00:00:00'` misses all points in time after 30-09-2020 00:00:00 even if the day portion is still 30-09-2020. There's a chance that is not intentional and `ACT_ENDDT >= '01-10-2019 00:00:00'  AND ACT_ENDDT < '01-10-2020 00:00:00'` is the better suited expression.

Comment: What is the datatype of `ACT_ENDDT`? If it's a string, your `between` won't work. If it's a `date, that's not how you write [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).

Comment: Is your data stored in an Oracle database? Oracle doesn't have functions like DATEFROMPARTS and GETDATE. If it's indeed Oracle, and you are coming from another database product, you will need to learn the Oracle dialect. Separately from this, pay close attention to the discussion of half-closed, half-open intervals in GMB's answer; that is a very common trap for beginners. Make sure you aren't missing dates (always date-times in Oracle!) from the last day of your interval. BETWEEN very rarely works well with date intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date artithmetics like this:

```
where act_enddt between trunc(sysdate, 'year') - interval '3' month
                    and trunc(sysdate, 'year') + interval '9' month - interval '1' day
```

I wonder whether a half-open interval may also be helpful:

```
where act_enddt >= trunc(sysdate, 'year') - interval '3' month
  and act_enddt <  trunc(sysdate, 'year') + interval '9' month
```

The difference between the two expressions is that the latter allows dates between October 30th at 00:00 and the end of that day. If your dates have no time component, this does not make a difference (and the second expression is a bit neater).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `extract()` to extract the year portion of `sysdate`, do arithmetic on it, like subtracting one, concatenate the month and day portion to complete it to be a date representation and convert this string to a `date` with `to_date()`.

That's

```
to_date(extract(YEAR FROM sysdate) - 1 || '-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

for your lower and

```
to_date(extract(YEAR FROM sysdate) || '-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

for your upper boundary.